# When creating a new element my foreignKey is always null. Sequelize, Node, Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I currently have a User model and a Team model that I want to associate.

User.js Model

```
"use strict";
module.exports = sequelize => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
        ...more fields
    }
    { tableName: "Users", timestamps: true }
  );

User.associate = function(models) {
    // 1 to many with skill
    User.hasMany(models.Skill, {
      foreignKey: "userId"
    });
    // 1 to many with team
    User.hasMany(models.Team, {
      foreignKey: "userId"
    });
  };

  return User;
};
```

Team.js Model

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Team = sequelize.define(
    "Team",
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      ...more fields
    },
    { tableName: "Teams", timestamps: true }
  );

  Team.associate = function(models) {

    Team.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "userId"
    });
  };
  return Team;
};
```

The column userId is automatically added to the team's table with the correct type (uuid) but no matter what I try it's always null.

I have tried just defining without options, and again the column was added, but set to null when a team was created.

1). Define the associations with no options.

```
User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Team);
}
```

Also, I have another table "Skills" that uses the same code but it works.

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Skill = sequelize.define(
    "Skill",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
    },
    { tableName: "Skills", timestamps: true }
  );

  Skill.associate = models => {
    Skill.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "userId"
    });
  };

  return Skill;
};
```

This is the method i'm using to create the team.

```
// Create a new team
exports.createTeam = async (req, res) => {
  // Get the user id from the session
  const userId = req.session.passport.user.id;

  const { title } = req.body;

  // Make sure the user hasn't already created a team with that title.
  const existingTeam = await models.Team.findOne({
    where: { title: title, userId: userId }
  });

  if (existingTeam !== null) {
    // Response and let the user know.
    ...
    return;
  }

  const defaultTeamValues = {
    title: title,
    ...
  };

  // No existing team was found with that title and created by that user.

  // Create it.
  const team = await models.Team.create(defaultTeamValues);

  // Done
  res.status(200).json(team);
};
```

New record in Team's table showing null value in foreign key (userId) column.
[image: new record with null value in foreign key (userId).]

I'm using pgAdmin 4 to view the tables and each table has the correct constraints fkeys too.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but I've read the docs and searched for similar issues but haven't found what I needed. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "its always null."? How did you create the data records?

Comment: @slideshowp2 - The userId from the User's table is not automatically added to the Team's table in the userId (uuid) column. I also updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I sort of figured out the problem. Instead of using

```
// Look for existing team
const existingTeam = await models.Team.findOne({
  where: { title: title, userId: userId }
});

if (existingTeam !== null) {
  ...
  return;
}

// No existing team was found with that title and created by that user.

// Create it.
const team = await models.Team.create(defaultTeamValues);
```

I switch to this method.

```
const team = await models.Team.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      title: title,
      userId: userId
    },
    // title and userId will be appended to defaults on create.
    defaults: defaultTeamValues
  });
```

The difference being that findOrCreate will append, the values in the where query, to the default values you provide.

This is what I did previously when adding new skills and that's why my Skills records had the userId and Teams did not.

So at this point, I don't know if my associations are even working because I'm actually just adding the userId value into the new record.

Back to reading the docs and testing.